# error and how to format hard disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

This morning I installed Playon Linux/Wine in order to have some Microsoft Windows software installed on my Ubuntu PC. After the made the installation an error was generated and I restarted my computer. After this restart, my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS was not able to start again. So I decided to install again Ubuntu. I had an USB ready with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, and I made the installation. Now this version works but the my problem is with the last Ubuntu and how should I format that partition from my hard disc.

Can I directly format /dev/sda 2? or should I format each part /dev/sda 6 and /dev/sda 5 independently?

I want to use this new partition to install Windows.

[picture my current partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfzel.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to install Windows you will need to format /dev/sda1 as ntfs (otherwise the Windows installer may not recognize the partition).

However this would only leave you with 52GB for the Windows partition. If you wish to remove your previous Ubuntu installation, you could remove the extended volume that was created by the install process (/dev/sda2) entirely.

So if you only require the use of Windows, and have no requirement for preserving data -- you could simply remove all of those partitions.

If you wanted to install Ubuntu again later, the installer would be able to configure your partitions again as you may require.

Comment: on /dev/sda1 is currently installed Ubuntu (new installation that I've made); on /dev/sda2 - is the partition that I want to format and which I want to use further for Windows installation. I think that I should format /dev/sda2 as ntfs using disks application for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at your screenshot of your disk partitions (it's kind of screwy), and knowing that you wish to (re)install Windows... the best recommendation that I can give you is to backup any documents/pictures/etc, and wipe the disk clean and start over... installing Windows FIRST, and Ubuntu SECOND. If you have a UEFI computer, make sure that you install BOTH with UEFI enabled. Secure boot should be disabled in your BIOS. Cheers, Al